# Change event for a multiple select

Tags: jquery

I would like to fire some code when the number of option elements within a multi select changes.

Here is what my html looks like:

```
<select id="id_foods_to" multiple="multiple" size="0" name="foods" class="filtered">
    <option value="1">stuff</option>
    <option value="2">more stuff</option>
<select>
```

And here is some code that I wrote which failed to accomplish my goal:

```
$("#id_foods_to").change(function () {

    alert('success!');

});
```

Also, I'm using this http://bitkickers.blogspot.ca/2010/05/reuse-djangos-filterhorizontal-admin.html

Comment: And is it not working?

Comment: `change` is called when the value change, i think you should add you code when you click on the arrow.

Comment: no sirree, it is not.

Comment: @Karl-André Gagnon - I tried that, but nothing is happening. I used live() and everything.

Comment: live() is deprecated, have you tried on()? And confirm if i am right, you want to fire the code when the number of option change, not when you click on an option right?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon - Yep, I'll have other events set up for double clicking options and using the arrow buttons

Answer (score 1):

you code works, just delete the select ending tag in the first line..

```
<select id="id_foods_to" multiple="multiple" name="foods" class="filtered">
    <option value="1">stuff</option>
    <option value="2">more stuff</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, when you click on the arrow, check if an item was added with this code :

```
var oldLength = $('#id_foods_to').children().length;
$(document).on('click', '.yourArrowClass', function(){
    if(oldLength != $('#id_foods_to').children().length){
        oldLength = $('#id_foods_to').children().length;
        //Your code here
    }
})
```

If this doesnt work, I will ask you to do a fiddle, so it will be easier to help you.